# Is there a way to delete the hidden data in a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I've split a pivot table using the show report filter pages. I convert each sheet into a separate workbook and id like to email but I cant have them able to see the other unfiltered data. Is there a way to remove the data that is excluded in each filter.